# C++ : cannot convert from 'char *' to 'char []' problem

Tags: c++

im not a c/c+ programmer ( i do know delphi), anyway im trying to compile a program written in c++, i'v changed it to accept some arguments( a path to a file, which is hardcoded in the original code)  from command line, 
the orignial line was

```
char Filepath[50] = "F:\\mylib\\*.mp3";
```

and i changed it to

```
char Filepath[50] = argv[1];
```

but i got  "cannot convert from 'char *' to 'char []'" error,
the main function is like

```
int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])
```

what should i do?? im using MSVC6.

thanks

Comment: `TCHAR* envp[]` and `char Filepath` are the same things.envp is equal to a char ** but Filepath is char *...
so you can convert directly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
char *Filepath = argv[1];
```

There's no need to allocate space for 50 characters when `argv[1]` already contains the string you want. Also, you don't have to decide what will be the maximum number of characters in the command line argument; that space is already allocated for you.

Note, however, that the above will *not* make a copy of the string, so if you intend to modify the string (perhaps by appending an extension or anything), then you will have to use `strcpy()` or similar solution. Handling strings in C is a lot more manual character-copying work than it is in Delphi.

Comment: If strcpy() worked, and you copied a command line argument into a 50 byte buffer, you have a buffer overflow waiting to happen. Make sure you check the length of the string and fail if it too long, or use a function like strdup().

Answer (score 6):

```
char Filepath[50] = argv[1];
```

In order to copy a string as in the above example you need to use strcpy (or any of its variants)

Another (better) way is to use C++ strings

```
std::string Filepath = argv[1];
```

that would copy the string as well.

Comment: Why is that better, janm?
For all we know the rest of the code uses char*.

Comment: Because there won't be overflow with a std::string, of course.

Comment: its 'better' in the sense that it works regardless of the string length of argv[1]

Answer (score 1):

#### strncpy(Filepath, argv[1], sizeof Filepath - 1)

Or, "what Greg said".

Comment: Surely it's better to fail than silently truncate a pathname ... and in this case you need to remember termination if the string is too long ...

Comment: If Filepath is global or static then it will always be null-terminated. I suppose it could be `auto`, then he should declare it as ` char Filepath[50] = { 0 };`, so the `strncpy()` call will always leave a null-terminated string. Anyway, it will fail soon enough, it's just a question of when.

Comment: Even if the string is null terminated (and we don't know how it was allocated), it will still be truncated and will still give the wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

Besides using strncpy() or std::string, it might be good to see why it goes wrong.
I would recommend checking this faq to see the ins and outs of pointers and arrays.
http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html